# Receiving multiple variables from ajax & writing it to text file using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I  need to save  user name & email to a text file. I can send 2 variables( strings) to php file  but I could only write one string to a text file. whenever I tried write both varibles ( name & email) it fails.  I'm new to both php & java script  . can you help me to fix this problem. Thank you

currently this is working just to get email.

**Javascript file (ajax part):**

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    data: { email : email , name : name  },
    success: function(){
        alert( name);
        console.log('name ' +  name);
    }
```

**PHP file:**

```
$file = 'details.txt';

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $uemail = $_POST['email'];

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $uemail = file_get_contents($file) . "\n" . $uemail;
    }

    $success = file_put_contents($file, $uemail);
}
```

Comment: Use implode() on the post. That should suffice.

Comment: hello ,  thnx for the answer . but I'm having problem applying it to php file.

Comment: Have you seen how `implode()` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_put_contents has a third parameter where can you specify whether you want to append to the file so it adds the new text to the end of the file. This way you wouldn't need to read the file first with file_get_contents:

```
file_put_contents($file, $_POST['name'] + ' ' + $_POST['email'], FILE_APPEND);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php